# GWT server side method should only be called by one client at the same time

Tags: gwt, synchronized

Is it possible to synchronize server-side methods, so that they can only be called by one client at once?

I tried this using the keyword "synchronized" on the server-side method. But it is still possible, that more than one client can call the method at the same time.

EDIT: The class containing the synchronized method is a thread-safe singleton.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to go back 80's ;) anyway for doing this, you can have an indicator of 'serving' while it is inside the service method and when it is out you can continue with next client. so you might need to have a queue...

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html#language):

> Multithreading and Synchronization: JavaScript interpreters are single-threaded, so while GWT silently accepts the synchronized keyword, it has no real effect. Synchronization-related library methods are not available, including Object.wait(), Object.notify(), and Object.notifyAll(). The compiler will ignore the synchronized keyword but will refuse to compile your code if the Object's related synchronization methods are invoked.